# Unable to locate annoying noise source in HP DV6 laptop

Tags: hardware-failure, fan, laptop-repair, hp-pavilion

I've had a [HP DV6-1340SS](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&tmp_geoLoc=true&product=4034002) laptop for about 3 years. Some months ago, I started hearing some kind of unusually loud fan noise with no apparent relation to CPU load. It's not the usual air sound, it probably sounds more like a helicopter, and appears randomly: I can use the PC for a whole day without noise, but it could be terribly noisy the following day.

I have tried replacing [the whole fan structure](http://www.ebay.es/itm/HP-COMPAQ-DV6-CPU-HEATSINK-FAN-ASSEMBLY-518435-001-/390410023975?pt=UK_Computing_Other_Computing_Networking&hash=item5ae6403427) with a unit I ordered on eBay, with no luck. Just as noisy. In the following [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWURkIueAJ0&feature=youtu.be), you can hear the noise (once I replaced the fan). The laptop is completely disassembled, it's just the motherboard (including fan).

I have also tried using my old fan with the new heatsink, and my old heatsink with the new fan, cleaning them internally... I have tried touching every part that could vibrate, but I haven't been able to find the noise source. The only clue I have is that the noise seems to stop when I lean the motherboard so that it's perpendicular to the floor.

There you have a couple of photos:
[image]
[image]

So my questions are:

- Should the fan or heatsink be assembled in any special way? I mean: should the screws be screwed the whole way?
- Could the new fan be also faulty? Isn't it too much of a coincidence?
- Is there any other part that could be vibrating?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: There *is* a piece of plastic stuck near the top of the last picture. Could there be a small bit of plastic or paper stuck near the fan that's flapping about in the wind?

Comment: @Bob Thnk you very much! I have tried holding that piece of plastic with my hand and I don't feel any kind of vibration. THe noise didn't stop either. To double check, I have tried disassembling the fan from the motherboard and turned it on as far as the power cord lets me. The noise keeps going, so I think I'll try to make the eBay seller send me another one.

Comment: Was this a brand new unit from ebay? If it was used, it may be because it was replaced due to making noise to begin with, so maybe no so coincidental if it is not brand new. The sound is like a kid that puts a playing card in the spokes of the bike. Maybe there is an imbalance of the blades making it wobble a bit. Is there any excessive play of the fan in the housing? Might need to be pressed down onto the shaft to give greater clearance to the housing. It is hitting something in there (the housing).

Answer (score 1):

If there's a speaker, also try disconnecting the speaker to check if the noise is really coming from a fan or from the speaker instead.  If there's a hard drive, also looks for signs that the noise is from the hard drive instead. If there's a floppy drive, also looks for signs that the noise is from the floppy drive instead.